# How to find out which node package is better in performance

Tags: node.js, xml, performance, profiling

I have a large xml which needs to be processed to extract a small amount of information. I found two packages which can parse the xml tag-by-tag. The 2 packages are : xml-flow and node-xml

I would require a package which loads a part of the xml file and performs the operation. Since the performance will depend on the amount on file loaded in memory (which I want to be smaller), I am looking for a way to measure that in the running process. How can I profile the memory in a simpler way?

One of the solutions I found was using process.memoryUsage() in the code to evaluate the memory used during runtime while the code is getting executed.

While using xml-flow, some of the stats that I received were:

```
info 2017-05-18 12:48:56 [0.449] [5] memory Usage:::  { rss: 57266176, heapTotal: 38379872, heapUsed: 24424120 }
info 2017-05-18 12:48:57 [0.928] [61] memory Usage:::  { rss: 76079104, heapTotal: 56954720, heapUsed: 20295616 }
info 2017-05-18 12:48:57 [1.133] [111] memory Usage:::  { rss: 76558336, heapTotal: 56954720, heapUsed: 32516896 }
```

Using node-xml, the stats were:

```
info 2017-05-18 12:42:11 [0.462] [8] memory Usage:::  { rss: 59572224, heapTotal: 39674208, heapUsed: 24561832 }
info 2017-05-18 12:42:12 [0.761] [74] memory Usage:::  { rss: 77697024, heapTotal: 58249056, heapUsed: 20546824 }
info 2017-05-18 12:42:12 [0.848] [114] memory Usage:::  { rss: 78032896, heapTotal: 58249056, heapUsed: 28871592 }
```

Comment: Why not to use some native C/C++ library to parse xml?

Comment: @osgx is right. Just use some native modules to parse, it will be a whole lot faster. Maybe post the xml source and your output desire so that we can suggest?